# Creating select tag using data from array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Im trying to create select in html using php based on values in array.

Array has some values I used this to check it

`echo '<pre>'; print_r($books_array); echo '</pre>';`

Looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbKIN.png

So there is field called name and then in html i create select:

```
<select id="books_select" id="book_select">
            <?php foreach($books_array as $book): ?>    
                    <option value="<?php echo $book['name']; ?>"<?php echo $book['name']; ?></option>

            <?php endforeach; ?>


    </select>
```

And for some reason its empty, I don't get why it looks okay to me and I cant find any problem ;/

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close option tag.

Replace it

```
<option value="<?php echo $book['name']; ?>"<?php echo $book['name']; ?></option>
```

With

```
<option value="<?php echo $book['name']; ?>"><?php echo $book['name']; ?></option>
```

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to close the option value so close it like so:

```
 <option value="<?php echo $book['name']; ?>"><?php echo $book['name']; ?></option>
```